# Importing series of text files into Matlab and save data as matrix (variables)

Tags: matlab, function, text, import, edit

I have a folder With .txt files. I would like to import these into Matlab. I have used the 'import data' tool with sucsess, but only for one file at the time.

I would like to have a method for processing all files in the folder and save them as variables, maybe with a number (1toX) as name. The file names are not sequential.

I'm hoping that I can use and edit the function/script created when importing 1 single file, and generate this to automatically import all files in the folder. This is because I get exactly what I want when importing 1 file. Just don't know how to import all the files in directory at once? (Some files are .dat). The format of the files are the same for all the .txt files. First rows of a file:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BeanSensor AX-3D

Mac Id : 00158D00000XX
Network Id : 00XX
Pan Id : 23FB
Sensor Id : 0
Sensor Label : Ch_X

Ratio : 1
Offset : 0
Unit : g

Date : 17.09.2014 05:32:24.000
Data acquisition cycle : 3604
Data acquisition duration : ~3600
Sampling rate : 100
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Measure Index;Measure Value

0;-0,0152
1;-0,0118
3;-0,0057
4;-0,0091
5;-0,0102
6;-0,0129
7;-0,0106
8;-0,0057
9;-0,0091
10;-0,0083
11;-0,0095
12;-0,0064
13;-0,0122
14;-0,0141
```

This is the script from iport tool:

```
%% Import data from text file.
% Script for importing data from the following text file:
%
%    C:\DATA\Dolmsundet\Streaming_0_x_0_0_x_00158D00000E03B0_17-09-2014_05.36.09_part000.txt
%
% To extend the code to different selected data or a different text file,
% generate a function instead of a script.

% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2015/02/03 13:48:57

%% Initialize variables.
filename = 'C:\DATA\Dolmsundet\Streaming_0_x_0_0_x_00158D00000E03B0_17-09-2014_05.36.09_part000.txt';
delimiter = ';';
startRow = 17;

%% Read columns of data as strings:
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
% This call is based on the structure of the file used to generate this
% code. If an error occurs for a different file, try regenerating the code
% from the Import Tool.
textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric strings to numbers.
% Replace non-numeric strings with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[1,2]
    % Converts strings in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric
    % strings with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and
        % suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\.]*)+[\,]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\.]*)*[\,]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if any(numbers=='.');
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\.\d{3})*\,{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(thousandsRegExp, '.', 'once'));
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            % Convert numeric strings to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
                numbers = strrep(numbers, '.', '');
                numbers = strrep(numbers, ',', '.');
                numbers = textscan(numbers, '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch me
        end
    end
end


%% Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells

%% Create output variable
Streaming0x00x00158D00000E03B01709201405 = cell2mat(raw);
%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars filename delimiter startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans raw col numericData rawData row regexstr result numbers invalidThousandsSeparator thousandsRegExp me R;
```

Hope this is understandable. 
All help appreciated :)

Comment: You could use `uigetfile` with `Multiselect` option to select all the files you are interested in. Afterwards you could use the `importdata` command in a loop, assigning every loop a new name to the matrix.

Comment: it would be easier to help you, if you provide a file (assuming they are formatted equally)

Comment: Thanks for help. How would you use importdata in a loop and assigning every loop a new name to the Matrix? I'm kind og novice in Matlab so step-by-step would be very helpful.

The files are measure data With some 100 000 lines. Startrow=17 as seen in script, lines before are unnecessary text. the rest are like this for each line(example): 
(line 1:) 0;-0,0123
(l2) 1;0,002
(l3) 3;-0,003
Where ';' is the delimiter and comma is the decimal denominator.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is, that your data uses decimal commas instead of dots. Because of that you can't use [**`importdata`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html), which is the best option otherwise and easy to handle within a loop. Do you see a way to process your file before? I usually just open the file and use crtl+h to substitute all commas with dots. Maybe you can automize that procedure using batch.

Comment: Using the 'import data' tool you can change this, so that you get dots when importing. That is why i was hoping to build on the Matlab-generated script, as this has already fixed it for me. The best thing for me would be a simple edit of the script/function so that it imports all .txt-files in the same directory, and saves each file as a single variable. In that way I can choose a file and plot it, or something in that direction.

Also, there are too many files for ctrl+h to be useful, timewise.

Comment: Shortly told, I just want to do what the import tool does for me, to several files in same directory, automatically.